# How to make filters in Android with Mysql and Json

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, filter

I want to filter data in android from Mysql table based on the selection of checkbox. There are more than 10 checkbox should i put if condition for all chances or is there any other way.

```
<?php   require("config.inc.php");


if (empty($_POST['brand']))  { 


    $response["success"] = 0;

    $response["message"] = "Please Enter required details ";

    die(json_encode($response));
}


$query = "SELECT product.*,specs.* from product,specs ";


  $query_params = array(

    ':PhoneMake' => $_POST['brand'],
    ':os_name' => $_POST['os'],
    //':D_apps' => $_POST['display'],
    ':ram' => $_POST['ram']     
);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}


$response = array();    
$response["Filter"] = array() ;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT product.*,specs.* from product,specs WHERE :PhoneMake='brand' AND :Os_ram='ram', AND :os_name='os', :AND D_apps='display' ");

  $query_params = array(

    ':PhoneMake' => $_POST['brand'],
    ':os_name' => $_POST['os'],
    //':D_apps' => $_POST['display'],
    ':ram' => $_POST['ram']     
);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
 }

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($response);



<h1>Filter</h1> 
<form action="filter.php" method="post"> 
   <div class="panel-heading filterhead">Filter by brand</div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" Samsung "> Samsung</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" Apple "> Apple</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="Nokia "> Nokia</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" HTC "> HTC</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" OnePlus "> OnePlus</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="  OnePlus"> OnePlus</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" OnePlus "> OnePlus</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="brand" value=" OnePlus "> OnePlus</label><br>
      </div>


      <div class="panel-heading filterhead">Price Filter</div>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Below ₹5,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹10,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹15,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹20,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹25,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹35,000</option>
            <option>Below ₹40,000</option>
            <option>Above ₹40,000</option>
        </select>
```

```
      <div class="panel-heading filterhead">Operating System</div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> Android</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> iOS</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> Asha OS</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> S40 / Symbian</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> Windows Phone</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="os"> Blackberry OS</label><br>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-heading filterhead">Display</div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="display" > Below 4 inches</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="display"> 4 inches to 5 inches</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="display"> 5 inches to 6 inches</label><br>
    </div>
```

RAM

```
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram"> 512 MB</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram"> 1 GB</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram"> 1 GB to 2 GB</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram"> 2 GB to 4 GB</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="ram"> Above 4 GB</label><br>
      </div>

</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> 
</form>
<?php
```

}

Please tell a proper way to choose with such checkbox. Thank you

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having?  What part of your code is not working or (possibly) working suboptimally?  How so?  Is this just a design question, or are you wondering if there is a feature of the HTML language that you do not know about?

Comment: My exact problem is, Since there are many checkboxes. How should i code PHP to filter data from database

Comment: Why are you using HTML checkboxes? Checkboxes can be multi selected or not even selected at all. You should be using radio boxes to force the user to select one and at most one item per category.

Comment: Just for sample i used html checkbox. And also i need user to use multi select and not even selected at all depends on their need. I am stuck with JSON. How to make Json code for such combination ?